# Command line arguments on a simple C++ Console Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to debug a simple program that is built on WSL using GCC in Visual Studio 2019. I have edited the launch.vs.json file to read

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "request": "launch",
      "projectTarget": "Simple",
      "name": "Simple",
      "externalConsole": true,
      "args": [ "p:", "/mnt/C/Linux/App" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The console app reads

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(argc > 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeList.txt reads

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Simple.solution")
# set the tool chain environment, build tools
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE Toolchain.CMake.txt)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("Simple")
```

The command line arguments are not picked up by the program when I launch the app.

Comment: You are aware that `assert` does nothing if your program is compiled in release mode, aren't you? Anyway try `assert(argc > 1)` -> `printf("%d\n", argc)`.

Comment: Yes, I am debugging the app and I am in debug mode.